# Leapmotion: Controller is never Connected

Tags: java, leap-motion

i have just started working on the leapmotion with java 
And am facing a problem which is that the controller is never connected(though i've installed the device driver and the Visualizer is working and everything is working fine )
my java version is "1.7.0_55"
and i'm using Ubuntu 14.04 LTs

Answer (score 1):

Check the leap motion drivers. My Sensor was detected as an usb Hub or a webcam. Ineeded to install the Drivers manually to make it work.

Although it's still not working sometimes (mostly after beeing connected to my convertable after it tuned itself into the standby mode). In this situations the only thing that helps is a quick computer restart.

Answer (score 0):

If you open the leap motion controller program, the leap icon will appear on the taskbar. Right click on it and make sure tracking is activated. That might be it. 
Otherwise give us more details.

Answer (score 0):

Click the leap icon on the taskbar and click resume. Also check the preferences' tracking options as Andrea suggested..

If these are not solving your problem and the 3 red lights on the top are not visible but the green light on the side is visible on your leap motion then try unplug and plug your cable from both your leap motion and computer. If still not working try restarting computer.

If also the green light is not visible then there might be something wrong with your hardware (usb port or the cable or the leap itself).

If all of the lights are visible but still not working (you cannot see your hands on the visualizer or the cam views) there may be something wrong with the computer's data receiving speed. For example some similar sensors are not working with the virtual box because of the mass amount of the data they are sending. Since if you are not using virtual os, honestly I don't know how to solve the problem. Try changing computer =)